# Benchmark of sql query against Ignite cache

Tags: ignite

I would ask if there is a benchmark report for running sql against Ignite cache. 
I looked through the https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs and didn't find one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GridGain publishes some benchmarks: https://www.gridgain.com/resources/benchmarks/gridgain-benchmarks-results

However, it's not clear what numbers are you looking for. Everything depends on your use case and on what you compare with. This is especially true for SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin. I read the SQL Query Benchmark section, `Results show a throughput of approximately 107,000 SQL based cache query operations per second`. What operations does it do? Did it mean to run 107000 sql query like 'select min' query per second? If so, then it is much faster than my test result.